# Wordpress Custom Menus Issue

Tags: menus, callbacks

In my template I'm using calls like this to output some custom menus:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('container_class' => 'secondary-navigation', 'theme_location' => 'secondary')); ?>
```

Ever since upgrading to WordPress 3.1.4 I get the full list of pages output on instead of the custom menu

I've seen fixes (via google) saying I should add the following to fix this:

```
'fallback_cb' => false,
```

While I understand why this might fix things for some people, when I do the menu doesn't output at all (not just unstyled content, no html is echoed).

My theme is heavily based on the twentyten default theme (from a code point of view), so I guess my question is does anyone have a fix which doesn't involve setting the fallback callback to false...

And/or does anyone know if this issue also exists in the latest RC for the new version?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have created that menu and associated it with with "secondary" menu location? Just asking...

Comment: Yes I have, as far as I can tell I've done everything by the book

Comment: If you get *no output* when adding `'fallback_cb' => false`, that means that *there is no menu applied to the specified Theme Location*. I think @Daniel Sachs is correct here. Go to `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menus` and verify that a menu is applied to the `secondary` Theme Location. (Also: what does your `register_nav_menus()` call in `functions.php` look like for this Theme Location?)